# Is there any simple way for the expectation of squared of ratio of random variables?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

So, for two random variables $A$ and $B$, I know that $\mathbf{E}[A]$, $\mathbf{E}(B)$, $Var(A)$ and $Var(B)$, I also know that $\mathbf{E}[A] = \mathbf{E}(B) + C$, I wonder if I can find a simple way to solve expectation of $X$, when:
$$
X = m - \dfrac{1}{1+(\dfrac{A}{B})^2}
$$
where $m$ is a constant. The only thing that I find related is the [Approximations for Mean and Variance of a Ratio](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf), but I don't know if I should expand everything following that, especially because that the explicit form of  $\mathbf{E}[A]$, $\mathbf{E}(B)$, $Var(A)$ and $Var(B)$ are also quite tedious. The only neat term is $C$.

So I'm writing this question here, and hope that, with a slight chance, there are some simple ways to solve this problem.

Comment: At the very least, you need information about how $A$ and $B$ covary.  After all, in the extreme case where $A=B$, $X$ is constant.  More generally, you have no hope of finding an exact expression for $E[X]$ unless the joint distribution of $(A,B)$ is something very special.

Comment: How is this "unclear"?  Perhaps it is unanswerable, but that's different, isn't it?